# How to use Makefile with gnuplot?

Tags: makefile, gnuplot

```
    (/)-----------------------+------------+   
     |                        |            |
     |                        |            |
  (task#1)--------+         (data)      (images)
     |            |           |            |
 (gnuplot)    Makefile     input.dat   output.png
     |                        .            ^
plotting.gpi<....input....<....            .
     .                                     .
     .........>.......output........>.......
```

According to my diagram, my question is that how to write `Makefile` to work with gnuplot this case?

The detail is:

I have `plotting.gpi` (gnuplot script) that read input from `input.dat` and generate output to `output.png` file. To execute script, we just type `gnuplot path/to/plotting.gpi` where `path/to/file`  depends on where do you execute `gnuplot` command if inside `gnuplot` folder. just `gnuplot plotting.gpi` is enough.

What had i tried?

I tried to write a very simple `Makefile` but seem like my understanding not good enough. my `Makefile` had some problem about file path and sometimes code in `Makefile` did not execute some lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a file structure like

```
.
├── data
│   └── input.dat
├── images
│   └── output.png
├── Makefile
└── task1
    ├── gnuplot
    │   └── ploting.gpi
    └── Makefile
```

You can type `make` either in root directory or in task1 directory.

The files have the following text

**Makefile**

```
all :
                make all -C task1

clean:
                make clean -C task1
```

**task1/Makefile**

```
IMAGES=../images/output.png

all : $(IMAGES)

clean:
                rm $(IMAGES)

../images/output.png : gnuplot/ploting.gpi ../data/input.dat
                gnuplot gnuplot/ploting.gpi
```

**ploting.gpi**

```
set term pngcairo 
set output '../images/output.png'
plot '../data/input.dat' using 1:2 with lp
set term x11
```

**input.dat**

```
1 1
2 2
3 0
4 2
5 3
```

The output.png is
[image]

Comment: Sorry @ctheo, i think have some mistake. `Makefile` should be in `task#1` folder.